# sh File Not found

Tags: java, docker, alpine-linux

I am using GraalVM to create a native image of petclinic in Java SpringBoot

Here is my DockerFile

```
FROM oracle/graalvm-ce:19.2.1

WORKDIR /opt/graalvm

RUN gu install native-image

COPY ./spring-petclinic/* /usr/local/

RUN native-image -jar /usr/local/spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar

FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /usr/local/

COPY --from=0 /opt/graalvm/spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT .

CMD yes
```

When I am using the image and do a `ls -la` I see the file `spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` which is the native image I want to execute

My problem append when I try to execute de binary. 
I get this error message:

```
sh: ./spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

I cannot execute a file which exists.

Comment: I'm think that you should copy spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar in /opt/graalvm

Comment: I think it should be `COPY --from=0  /usr/local/spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar .`